# Change panels position

Tags: interface, windows, panel

if i want customize my blender in source codes, is it possible to define default position of panels ?
for example by default, we have blender as like as follow :

[image]

properties panel in right, info panel in top, time panel, tools panel, ... etc.

for example i want expertise panel in top ( with a new arrangement ) when blender open

Comment: This question is off-topic because it about building a custom version of blender. See [what questions are off-topic #4](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/6/935)

Comment: Um... you can customize the UI without building Blender from custom source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the layout the way you want it to be, then use *File->Save Startup File*.

Locate the startup.blend that [was saved](https://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/installing/configuration/directories.html) and place it in [`release/datafiles/startup.blend`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/datafiles/) within the source tree used to build your copy of blender.

Comment: layout adjusting is in that **blend** file ? or in the codes ?

Comment: The default startup.blend begins as a startup file that has been saved with blender, during the build process it is used to generate a c file (startup.blend.c) that you can find inside the build directory, which contains an array containing a binary representation of the file, This c-file is used to compile the default startup.blend within blender's binary file.

Answer (score 2):

You can save your current file, including preferences and window layout as startup file by selecting *File > Save Startup File* or hitting *Ctrl + U*

Comment: thank you but i want do that in the codes